# get the nested array from mongoose and sorted by createdAt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is my data model

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e",
    "completedExams": [
      {
        "_id": "5f778650cbc02f43e25064e0",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:58:08.146Z",
        "exam": "Test-1",
        "score": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f77868ccbc02f43e25064e2",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:59:08.493Z",
        "exam": "Test-2",
        "score": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this

```
User.findOne({"_id": "5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e"}).sort({'completedExams.createdAt': -1}).select({'completedExms.createdAt': 1, 'completedExams.score': 1, 'completedExams.exam': 1});
```

I'm getting this from that query

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e",
    "completedExams": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:58:08.146Z",
        "exam": "Test-1",
        "score": 2
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:59:08.493Z",
        "exam": "Test-2",
        "score": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want to get this with sorted

```
    [
      {
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:59:08.493Z",
        "exam": "Test-2",
        "score": 1
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2020-10-02T19:58:08.146Z",
        "exam": "Test-1",
        "score": 2
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried this

User.findOne({"_id": "5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e"}).sort({'completedExams.createdAt': -1}).select({'completedExms.createdAt': 1, 'completedExams.score': 1, 'completedExams.exam': 1});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e") } },
  { $unwind: "$completedExams" },
  { $sort: { "completedExams.createdAt": -1 } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$completedExams" } }
])
```

For these functions you have to use the aggregation framework, i.e. `findOne` does not work.

But many operations also accept an aggregation pipeline as input parameter.

See [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dlmEZe6RzPI)

Comment: it's just returning the _id    User.findOne(req.query,[
      {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
      {$unwind: "$completedExams"},
   ]);

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framework to sort the array in descending order.

```js
User.aggregate([
  // Initial document match
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId('5f7753db63cce11af6a7146e')
    }
  },
  // Expand the completedExams array into a stream of documents
  {
    $unwind: '$completedExams'
  },
  // Sort in descending order
  {
    $sort: {
      'completedExams.createdAt': -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      completedExams: {
        $push: '$completedExams'
      },
    }
  }
])
```